# How to create the log file for each record in a specific format using java util logging framework

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I want to create the log file per request in the format below, using java util logging.

```
YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.log
```

Anybody please let me know how can I achieve this using java util logging?

Comment: per which request? Do you have existing code we can see using logging?

Comment: I have a stand alone SE application. When I execute that application each time I want to create different log files according to the time format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FileHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) doesn't support generating file names by [date and time](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4738412) from the LogManager.

If you want to generate a file name on startup you can subclass the FileHandler and create a static method to generate your file name using a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  The [LogManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) supports a 'config' option that will also allow you to install custom code to setup and install a FileHandler.

```
public class RollingFileHandler extends FileHandler {

    public RollingFileHandler() throws IOException {
        super(fileName(), 0, 1, true);
    }

    private static String fileName() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("'%h'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
}
```

If you want to generate a file name per each LogRecord you have to create a custom [Handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html) that will create and close a FileHandler on each publish.

```
public class DatedFileHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public synchronized void publish(LogRecord r) {
        if (isLoggable(r)) {
            try {
                FileHandler h = new FileHandler(fileName(r), 0, 1, true);
                try {
                    h.setLevel(getLevel());
                    h.setEncoding(getEncoding());
                    h.setFilter(getFilter());
                    h.setFormatter(getFormatter());
                    h.setErrorManager(getErrorManager());
                    h.publish(r);
                } finally {
                    h.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException | SecurityException jm) {
                this.reportError(null, jm, ErrorManager.WRITE_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        super.setLevel(Level.OFF);
    }

    private String fileName(LogRecord r) {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("'%h'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date(r.getMillis()));
    }
}
```